# Create geoprocessing tool using ArcPy that buffers multiple inputs and then merges and dissolves them into one final output

Tags: arcpy, buffer, python-script-tool

I am trying to create a geoprocessing tool in ArcMap by way of Python that will accept multiple inputs (points, lines, and polygons) buffer them based on user input, and then take the results and merge them and then dissolve them into one single polygon.

Any suggestions or different approaches?

My plan is once this part works then the feature classes stored in the working.gdb would then be merged and dissolved and the output saved. I am making this tool for my team so nothing can be hard coded.

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
import os

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.env.workspace = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
tempworkspace = arcpy.env.workspace
arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(tempworkspace, "working.gdb")
workinggdb = (tempworkspace + "\working.gdb")
inputfc = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
bufferdistance = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
outputfc = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)

fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(inputfc)

for fc in fcs:
    bufferoutput = workinggdb + "\buffer_" + fc
    arcpy.Buffer_analysis(fc, bufferoutput, bufferdistance, "FULL", "ROUND", 
    "NONE", "", "PLANAR")
```

Comment: Are you using ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap?  What happens when you run tool that you have presented the code for?

Comment: Is the buffer not working?  It may be because you're inputting the distance as a string.  Either convert that string to a number, or use `arcpy.GetParameter(2)`

Comment: Polygeo I am using ArcMap. The temporary GDB is created and that is all. None of the input shapefiles are buffered and I get no errors.

Comment: jbalk I just tried that and it didn't work. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Make sure the parameter is set to number and not string.  Or, to be sure, use `float(bufferdistance)`

Comment: jbalk the parameter is set to be a linear unit. I have used this exact set up in other scripts and tools and have not had issues with the buffer tool executing. It has to be somewhere else.